# How to solve conditional probability problem using bayesian algorithm

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am trying to solve

> An agent learning to categorise news articles in two topics, World
>   (W) and Finance (F). Out of $100$ articles, $40$ were classified as W, and $20$ of
>   the articles were classified as both W and F. What is the value of conditional
>   probability of an article being classified as F?*

The algorithm which I am assuming right for this question is

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{ P(B)}. $$

But how to specifically categorize F ? and take specific values for equation ? or I am assuming wrong formula ?

Comment: 40 were classified as P?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes 40 were P, Thanks for formatting tips

Comment: You state there are two topics, W and F. Yet 40 were classified as P. What does P denote?

Comment: I change the question, its W.

Answer (score 0):

If the 40 W includes the number 20 W and F, then
$$P(F|W) = \frac{P(FW)}{P(W)} = \frac{20/100}{40/100} = \frac{20}{40} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
If 40 W does not include the 20 W and F, then notice that
$$P(W) = P(W\bar F)+P(WF) = \frac{40}{100}+\frac{20}{100} = \frac{60}{100}.$$
So,
$$P(F|W) = \frac{P(FW)}{P(W)}= \frac{20/100}{60/100} = \frac{20}{60} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: why $P(WF) + P(WF)$ ?

Comment: @ARG No, there is a bar over the first $F$, and it is true by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).